# Is it possible to go back two referral URLs in PHP?

Tags: php, url, redirect, referrer

I currently use this snippet to create a go back to the previous page button:

```
<?php
    $referral_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (strpos($referral_url, 'product/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to previous product</a>';
    } else if (strpos($referral_url, 'products/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
    } elseif (!empty($referral_url)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</a>';
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
?>
```

I am however experiencing a couple issues with this back button, if a user adds the product to cart, the referrer URL becomes itself, trapping the back link in a loop.

Is there any existing methodology to allow me to check if the referrer URL matches the current, if so use the link before the referrer URL?

So it would be something like this:

```
<?php
    $referral_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    var_dump($referral_url);

    $current_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    var_dump($current_url);

    if ($referral_url == $current_url) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER[1]'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
    } else if (strpos($referral_url, 'product/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to previous product</a>';
    } else if (strpos($referral_url, 'products/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
    } elseif (!empty($referral_url)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</a>';
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
?>
```

Stating the obvious but this is the additional code:

```
$current_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
var_dump($current_url);

if ($referral_url == $current_url) {
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER[1]'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
}
```

Where:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER[1]']
```

Is not a real thing...

But what is? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this unless you keep track in your code.

Comment: Don't build functionality that relies on `HTTP_REFERER`. Not only can anyone spoof it, but it's also not always present.

Comment: It is possible in jQuery. So imagine there will be the equivalent in PHP

Comment: Javascript runs on the client (in this case) while PHP runs on the server. Two completely different environments and use cases.

Comment: I require a back link to a filtered view of products, the filters being applied through the URL query string. So I require the previous URL.

Comment: Why can't you just do it in JS? `history.go(-1):` goes to the previous page. It's the browser that stores the history, not the server.

Comment: Yeah I am going to use that, but with a (-2). I just thought someone may know of a PHP way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved it, with a mix of JS and PHP:

```
<?php
    $referral_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    var_dump($referral_url);

    $current_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    var_dump($current_url);

    if ($referral_url == $current_url) {
        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:history.go(-2)" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
    } else if (strpos($referral_url, 'product/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to previous product</a>';
    } else if (strpos($referral_url, 'products/') !== false) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back to products</a>';
    } elseif (!empty($referral_url)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'" class="referral-url" title="Back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</a>';
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
?>
```

I would still very much be interested in the answer should anyone know how to achieve this with PHP.